# How to find the shortest route between (0,0) and (4,4) in a 5x5 matrix, given one horizontal or vertical translation per step

Tags: python, shortest-path

I've coded the following to describe the problem I have in my mind:

```
row = int(input("How many rows? "))
column = int(input("How many columns? "))
sample_map = []
to_append =[]
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        to_append.append("_")
    sample_map.append(to_append)
    to_append=[]

def add_to_map(indicator=input("What symbol do you want to use? ")):
    x_coordinate = int(input("Input x coordinate. Note: (0,0) starts at top left. "))-1
    y_coordinate = int(input("Input y coordinate. "))-1

    sample_map[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = indicator

continue_to_add =input("Do you want to add something to the map? Answer yes or no. ")
while(continue_to_add=="yes"):
    add_to_map()
    continue_to_add =input("Do you want to add something else to the map? Answer yes or no. ")

sample_map[0][0] = "S"
sample_map[row-1][column-1] = "E"

for element in sample_map:
    print(element)
```

Consider the following output:
[image]

In the spaces where there is an X, you cannot move into that space. So in the above picture, a possible route may be the following:
(0,0)->(0,1)->(0,2)->(0,3)->(1,3)->(2,3)->(3,3)->(4,3)->(4,4)

A total of eight steps.
Ideally, the code should be able to adapt to the path given changes in the locations of the Xs on the chart.

If the Xs occur in a way that prevents any movement (i.e, Xs at (0,1),(1,1), and (1,0), it should return -1 or indicate in some other way no path is possible.)

Comment: Maybe A* would be useful

Comment: Question for cs.stackexchange

Comment: Co-signing on some other comments. You might want to ask the [CS stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), and you are probably looking for [A*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) or some A*-like algoirthm ([D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*) for example).

Comment: Thanks guys, will check with CS stack exchange, thought they were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments on your question imply (suggesting the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)), you want to frame this as a **graph theory/network** problem:

- each position on the grid is a node
- nodes share an edge if exactly one coordinate differs by exactly 1
- `X` nodes (and their associated edges) are deleted

The problem then becomes, find the shortest path in the graph between two nodes. If the nodes are not in the same connected component, there is no such path.